Poor sound quality on Asus UX5304MA with Ubuntu 24.04
I've installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a new ASUS UX5304MA. Sound quality on the internal speakers is awful (lots of clicking and popping, and the audio sounds like I'm listening through a wall). On the audio jack, audio is completely unusable--I only hear a series of extremely loud clicks, no recongizable audio at all.
Audio quality is great on Windows, so it seems like this is a driver issue rather than a hardware issue.
inxi -SMA gives:
System:
  Host: michael-zenbook Kernel: 6.8.0-47-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ASUS Zenbook S 13 UX5304MA_UX5304MA
    v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: UX5304MA v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: UX5304MA.301 date: 03/19/2024
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Meteor Lake-P HD Audio driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-47-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active

Please let me know if any other information would be helpful. Thank you!
